# Pivot table to extract distinct values

Tags: excel, pivot, distinct

I have a table with various kids that have various fruits. Some kids have more than one fruit of a kind, and some fruits are owned by various kids.

I want to know for each kid what kind of fruit he has, each fruit listed only once.

The problem is the left table, the right is the wanted solution

[image: The problem is the left table, the right is the wanted solution]

Whatever I tried so far failed in some way or another.

Is there a formula to do that?
I actually have 26000 rows of that data, is it possible to do that with a pivot table?

Comment: Maybe, remove duplicate rows? Or build another query with powerquery?

Comment: As @JvdV writes, just use the `Remove Duplicates` tool (on the Data Ribbon --> Data Tools tab)